# Delete directory tree that contains read-only directories

Tags: rm

If you run `rm -rf dir` and `dir` contains read-only directories then it will fail to remove any files in that directory.

Is there any way to make `rm` recognise that and `chmod` the directory to be writable first?

I can `chmod -R o+w dir` first but that's going to be slower than doing it only when necessary.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to make `rm` recognise that and `chmod` the directory to be writable first?

The `rm` command requires write access to a directory to be able to remove files and directories from it.

Your options are either

- Fix the permissions to ensure that non-writable directories are writable (`chmod -R u=rwx {toplevel_directory}; rm -rf {toplevel_directory}`)
- Use root privileges to get implicit write access (not really recommended: `sudo rm -rf {toplevel_directory}`)

If you're seriously concerned about speed optimisation you could write a script or function to retry the `rm` only if it failed first time:

```
rm-rf() {
    local item rs=0 ss=0

    for item in "$@"
    do
        if [ -e "$item" ]
        then
            rm -rf "$item"
            rs=$?

            if [ $rs -gt 0 ]
            then
                # Try again
                chmod -R u=rwx "$item" 2>/dev/null
                rm -rf "$item" 2>/dev/null && rs=0
            fi

            [ $rs -eq 0 ] && echo "Removed: $item" >&2
        else
            echo "Skipping: $item" >&2
            rs=1
        fi

        # Count the number of failed arguments
        [ $rs -gt 0 ] && ((ss++))
    done
    return $ss
}
```